# How can i find the player local position plus 1.5 on each 4 directions?

Tags: unity, c#

I know the current player position:

```
private void Test()
    {
        Vector3 playerPosition;
        playerPosition = player.localPosition;

        Vector3 fwd = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 left = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.left);
        Vector3 right = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        Vector3 back = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.back);
    }
```

Now i want to find from the player position each direction position + 1.5f from the player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply by 1.5, no?

```
Vector3 rightOnePointFive = player.localPosition + player.right * 1.5f;
Vector3 leftOnePointFive = player.localPosition - player.right * 1.5f; 
Vector3 forwardOnePointFive = player.localPosition + player.forward * 1.5f;
Vector3 backOnePointFive = player.localPosition - player.forward * 1.5f;
```